# MATLAB GUI handles

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, handle, matlab-gui, objecthandles

I have question about using "handles" in Matlab Callback function.
I don t know how to use the same thing twice. Please help me.

So,I build Matlab GUI and I have callback function for upload image:

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

handles = guidata(hObject); 
[filename pathname]=uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.bmp'},'File Selector'); 
image=strcat(pathname, filename)
handles.data1=imread(image)
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(handles.data1);
set(handles.edit1,'string',filename)
set(handles.edit2,'string',pathname)
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

,and I have callback fuction for converting the same image to "Gray Scale":

```
function Gray_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

handles = guidata(hObject); 
axes(handles.axes2);
img=handles.data1;
x=imread(img);

y=rgb2gray(x); %function to convert an rgb image to gray scale

imshow (y)
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

,but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: “It doesn’t work” is not useful. Please describe what happens and what you expect to happen. Also include here how you link these callbacks to GUI elements and so forth. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Sorry...Uploading image works, i pressed the button and uploaded image, but when I press "Gray Scale" button it doesn t work. So, I think that lines img=handles.data1;
x=imread(img); in Gray_Callback function don t work anything..Is it better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first function says

```
handles.data1=imread(image)
```

Then your second function says

```
img=handles.data1;
x=imread(img);
```

Since `img` contains image data, not the name of a file, what does `imread(img)` mean?

I presume you want to work directly with the image data `img` here, not use `imread` at all.